# Which screen sizes consider when designing for Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, screen

I'm writing Windows Phone 8.1 application (I don't care about tablets and desktops in this case) and I'm not sure which screen size psds should I ask from a graphic designer?

I have read design guidlines for Windows Phone 8.1, I get the system of scaling images and their name convention, but I haven't found the advice which screen sizes should I consider in real?
I got a psd from graphic designer in size 720x1280 and there is a background image. Is it enough?

If I get it right, Nokia Lumia 1520 has a screen resolution 1920 x 1080 so I need also that size, right?

How scaled psds do you usually get from a graphic designer for Windows Phone?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows (Phone) uses a scale factor depending on the pixel density (DPI) of the device. Therefore, there is no *default resolution* any longer.

Screens with high DPI get a high Scale Factore applied, so all resources are scaled up together with the (all vector based) UI.

Image assets get automatically scaled up, but you can add the scaled items by hand for better results.

So the answer to your question probably is: **Yes, it is enough, but you can add additional higher resolution assets for better results.**

---

Also, Phone Store apps allow you to create **bundles**, containing only the assets for the device you install the app on (if it is installed from the store), so you don't need to care about package/download size.

See:

- [Quickstart: Using file or image resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965325.aspx)
- [Guidelines for scaling to pixel density](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465362.aspx)

Comment: Ok, the scale factor is _pixels / width * platform constant_. Platform constant depends on viewing distance of device (phone/tablet/PC). What is the platform constant for a phone?

Comment: As statet in the Guidelines (see link above), it is 1.0, 1.4 or 2.4 depending on the DPI (Although I think it has been expanded to .2 steps in between). You can find some example in the Devices Window in visual Studio Xaml editor.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you are building for Silverlight or Windows XAML.

For Silverlight, all phones are considered to be 480 x 800 pixels (for 15:9 devices) or 480 x 854 pixels (for 16:9 devices). The platform will map each of those effective pixels to either 1, 1.5, 1.6, or 2.25 physical pixels depending on the actual resolution of the panel (WVGA, 720p, WXGA, or 1080p). So all UI designs should be built for 480px wide, but you can build higher-resolution assets if needed.

For Windows XAML apps, the story is more complicated. The effective resolution of phones ranges from 384 x 640 up to around 450 x 800 (and possibly higher), based mostly on the physical size of the device. Scale factors range from 1.0 to upwards of 2.4, and each effective pixel is "bigger" in terms of actual physical size compared to Silverlight pixels.

There is more information in my [//build talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-541)

Comment: Yes, thank you. But what about the fonts? When I get the PSD with font of size 30pt, what should I use in xaml (Windows Phone 8.1 XAML)?
And is the font scaled as well as images are?

Comment: Beware of point sizes. Adobe uses 1/72 inch and then rasterizes that based on the DPI settings of the document. Windows uses 1/96 inch and rasterizes based on desktop scale factor. XAML uses effective pixel vales (not points). So either you need to do some math (based on the PSD's DPI) or count individual pixels.